# find matching row based on multiple columns (sequence of columns doesn't matter)

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

I have a table structure like this

```
PersonID   |  Name   |  ItemID1  |  ItemID2  |ItemID3  | ItemID4
1          |  kk     |   1       |  2        |NULL     | NULL
2          |  KK     |   1       |  NULL     | 2       | NULL
```

In the above data set, two persons are same if they have same name and same set of items(sequence of items doesn't match here). Basically, in row 1, person name is KK and list of items are 1 and 2, same is the case with row 2.Hence these 2 are matching rows.

I need to write a sql query to find these matching rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will make all values of columns (itemID columns) in a single column

```
   SELECT id,name,  case WHEN itemid1 IS NOT NULL THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10), itemid1) + ','
 else '' end  +  case WHEN itemid2 IS NOT NULL THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10), itemid2) + ',' else
 ''  end  +  case WHEN itemid3 IS NOT NULL THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10), itemid3) + ','  else '' 
end +  case WHEN itemid4 IS NOT NULL THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10), itemid4) + ','  else '' end  
 as itemid FROM emp
```

now you have to write a function to order the comma separated values of ItemID column and return the string. thats all.. now you can easily do exact match.. but this won't be giving good performance..

Creating a computed column with same query will get you performance..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this breaks 'data normalization', but perhaps you know that and need to implement this based on some constraint or because it is in general easier for your solution.

Here's one solution (there are many):

First use a UNION ALL Query in a VIEW to Flatten your data. Let's call this view viewFlattedPeopleWithItems (You could also just use a temporary table or virtual table!):

```
SELECT PersonID, Name, ItemID1 as ItemID
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT PersonID, Name, ItemID2
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT PersonID, Name, ItemID3
FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT PersonID, Name, ItemID4
FROM TABLE
```

Then to find duplicate data:

```
SELECT Name, Item, COUNT(*)
FROM viewFlattedPeopleWithItems
GROUP BY Name, Item
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you wanted, you could also use this second query to create a view or temp table or similar and then join back to the union all query to get the PersonID values that have duplication.

Comment: this will give me list of duplicates based on personid/name and itemid.. I am actualy thinking of a computed column which will hold checksum of all 4 column values and i just need to compare the checksum of 2 records to check if they are duplicate... but i guess nulls are creating problem... select * from TABLE group by name,computedcolumn

Comment: In that case why don't you just use ISNULL() function and convert nulls to zeros... i.e. ISNULL(ItemIDx, 0)

Comment: The problem of duplicates can be solved by using Row_Number() partitioned over personid and name...basically creating keys where you don't have them.